# Data Mb Limit Client Side Apps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cross-browser

Working with angularjs it's very easy to run through LOTS of data on the client.

Is there a rule of thumb as to how much data I want to work with at once?  I'm transferring files with a few mb of text data and don't seem to be running into too much trouble.  (Barring I'm not displaying all my records at once).

Is there a point where you think you should still be working off the server?  How much is too much?  Is it browser/os/device dependent?

Answer (score 1):

I think this strongly depends on which browsers you are targeting.  If you are targeting IE8 you will have no were near the same performance as if a user was using the latest chrome release.

As a rule of thumb I tend to want the experience (speed, smoothness, user ability etc) when you visit sites I develop to be the same across all browsers and versions.  To do this I do most of the heavy lifting on the server and send down mostly pre-packages, pre-parsed data sets for the client to display.

You should be testing your application across the full spectrum of browsers you support and you will find areas each browser excels and is not as good as it's rivals.  You can then tweak accordingly.

However, some would argue if you are targeting the latest browsers that to reduce cpu cycles on the server you should be push processing to the client.  I would agree here if you can ensure your using are using the latest browsers on fairly decent machines with good internet connections.